# HTML Select item show div and post problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I am confused. I want two products to be selected. These products will be open by clicking the button. The selection will be made on the screen that opens. And the selected product will replace the button clicked.

I can show the products by clicking the button. I even got the result I wanted as text with jquery. But I used `<select>` `<option>` for this. There will be no drop-down list and only one will be selected. The selected image will replace the clicked area. I couldn't :(

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".showbutton, .showbutton img").click(function(event) {
    var buttonName = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    var buttonNo = buttonName.slice(4);
    var boxName = "#box" + buttonNo;
    $(boxName).fadeIn(300);
  });
  $(".closebtn").click(function() {
    $(".box").fadeOut(200); 
  });
  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(".box").fadeOut(200);
  });
  $(".innerbox").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
div.showbutton {}

div.showbutton:hover {}

.box {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.innerbox {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 5% auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 25px #ccc;
}

#box1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#box2 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.closebutton {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closebtn {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="builder" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="showbutton" id="link1">
    click for first items
  </div>
  <div id="box1" class="box">
    <div class="innerbox">
      <div class="closebutton">
        <div class="closebtn">X</div>
      </div>
      - item1.png - item2.png - item3.png
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="showbutton" id="link1">
    click for second items
  </div>
  <div id="box1" class="box">
    <div class="innerbox">
      <div class="closebutton">
        <div class="closebtn">X</div>
      </div>
      - item1.png - item2.png - item3.png
    </div>
  </div>
```

JSFIDDLE example of my codes: https://jsfiddle.net/j5fqhat6/

Comment: `But I used <select> <option> for this.` Where? --- `There will be no drop-down list and only one will be selected.` That is unclear... Can you rephrase?

Comment: <select> <option> I've tried. But what I want to do is not make a choice as a droptown. Having the pictures selected in a different way than droptown.

Comment: I know this is not working but the logic is as follows: <select> <div><option><img></option></div> So instead of droptown like in the jsfiddle example, I need to be able to define free styles for options and I want all options to appear on the screen. Of course, the selected image, which is the continuation of my problem, should replace the clicked place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add data attribute to your `kutu` div this will help us to identify from where click event has been occurred .So, whenever your `gosterButonu` is been clicked you can use this `data-id` to add selected images text to your `gosterButonu` div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gosterButonu, .gosterButonu img").click(function(event) {
    var butonAdi = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(butonAdi)
    //if on click of button you want to remove active class
    // $("div[data-id="+butonAdi+"]").find("li").removeClass("active") 
    $("div[data-id=" + butonAdi + "]").fadeIn(300);
  });
  $(".kapatButonu").click(function() {
    var data_id = $(this).closest(".kutu").data("id");
    $("#" + data_id).text($(this).closest(".icKutu").find("li.active").text())
    $(".kutu").fadeOut(200);

  });
  $(".kutu").click(function() {
    $(".kutu").fadeOut(200);
  });
  $(".icKutu").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  //on click of li
  $(".images li").click(function() {
    //remove active class from other lis
    $(this).closest(".images").find("li").not(this).removeClass("active")
    //add active class to li which is clicked
    $(this).addClass("active");

  })
});
```

```css
div.gosterButonu {}

div.gosterButonu:hover {}

.kutu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.icKutu {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 5% auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 25px #ccc;
}

#kutu1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#kutu2 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.kapatButonuCerceve {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.kapatButonu {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="builder" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="gosterButonu" id="link1">
    clickfor first items
  </div>
  <!--added data-id which matched with the div above-->
  <div id="kutu1" data-id="link1" class="kutu">
    <div class="icKutu">
      <div class="kapatButonuCerceve">
        <div class="kapatButonu">X</div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <!--added ul li-->
      <ul class="images">
        <li>- item1.png</li>
        <li> - item2.png </li>
        <li>- item3.png</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gosterButonu" id="link2">
    click for second items
  </div>
  <!--added data-id which matched with the div above-->
  <div id="kutu2" data-id="link2" class="kutu">
    <div class="icKutu">
      <div class="kapatButonuCerceve">
        <div class="kapatButonu">X</div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul class="images">
        <li>- item1.png</li>
        <li> - item2.png </li>
        <li>- item3.png</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```